# Add two series indexed by distinct but overlapping intervals

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following series:

```
import pandas as pd

index1 = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(1, 3), (2.5, 4), (6, 7)])
x = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=index1)

index2 = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([(1, 2), (5, 6.5)])
y = pd.Series([10, 20], index=index2)

z = x+y
```

Ideally, this is how I would like z to look:

```
(1.0, 2.0]    11
(2.0, 2.5]    1
(2.5, 3.0]    3
(3.0, 4.0]    2
(4.0, 5.0]    0
(5.0, 6.0]    20
(6.0, 6.5]    23
(6.5, 7.0]    3
```

Of course, when I do add them, I get a bunch of `NaN`s, because the indices don't align.

Should I upsample, and then add?  (Also... is there a fancy way to downsample in pandas?)

How would I deal with one of the series having overlapping intervals inside its own index?

#### Context:

I'm trying to keep track of the number of students who have a class going on at a certain time.

I've scraped the class schedule, and I'm running into a problem when classes start and get out at different times.

Comment: Did you try `pd.concat([x,y])`?

Comment: ``pd.concat([x, y])`` doesn't add on the overlap.  It just stacks them all together.

Comment: Does `z = x+y` add on the overlap? I didn't thought so

Comment: @davidbilla that's what he said.

Comment: what do the values of the index interval represent

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach, hope it's self-explained:

```
# gather x and y and separate start and end time
df = (pd.concat((x,y))
        .to_frame(name='val')
        .assign(start=lambda x: x.index.left,
                end=lambda x: x.index.right)
     )

# unique time point
idx = (df.index.left.to_series()
    .append(df.index.right.to_series())
    .drop_duplicates()
    .to_frame(name='pt')
    .assign(dummy=1)
)

# cross join, query the valid entries, and sum:
(df.assign(dummy=1)
   .merge(idx, on='dummy')
   .query('start < pt <= end')
   .groupby('pt')
   .val
   .sum()
)
```

Output (note that `pt` is the end point for each interval, the start point is the previous end point).

```
pt
2.0    11
2.5     1
3.0     3
4.0     2
6.0    20
6.5    23
7.0     3
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

flatten all left and right values of `x.index` and `y.index` and filter by unique values. Construct new IntervalIndex from these unique values. Using listcomp on the new IntervalIndex checking and slicing on overlaps of `x`, `y` to construct final output

```
arr = np.unique(x.index.append(y.index).to_tuples().to_numpy().sum())

Out:
array([1. , 2. , 2.5, 3. , 4. , 5. , 6. , 6.5, 7. ])

iix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(arr)
s = pd.Series([x[x.index.overlaps(ix)].sum() + y[y.index.overlaps(ix)].sum() 
                            for ix in iix], index=iix)

Out[379]:
(1.0, 2.0]    11
(2.0, 2.5]     1
(2.5, 3.0]     3
(3.0, 4.0]     2
(4.0, 5.0]     0
(5.0, 6.0]    20
(6.0, 6.5]    23
(6.5, 7.0]     3
dtype: int64
```